# Array that takes two strings: Create function to transpose them from top to bottom instead of left to right

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is what I am trying to do: I am a little lost. Do I use the map() and slice() methods for this? I am using javascript.
You will be given an array that contains two strings. Your job is to create a function that will take those two strings and transpose them, so that the strings go from top to bottom instead of left to right.

e.g. transposeTwoStrings(['Hello','World']);

should return

H W
e o
l r
l l
o d
A few things to note:

There should be one space in between the two characters
You don't have to modify the case (i.e. no need to change to upper or lower)
If one string is longer than the other, there should be a space where the character would be

Comment: Please do share what you've done so far, and we can help you improve it

Comment: What datatype is `H W e o l r l l o d`? Is it a single string containing line breaks?

Comment: What would happen if the strings are not equal length?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me.

Answer (score 0):

Edited because I didn't see the criteria that the strings might not be the same length:

```
let testArr = ['Hello','World'];

function transpose(arr) {
  let result = '';
  let counter = 0;
  while(arr[0][counter] || arr[1][counter]) {
    result += arr[0][counter] || ' ';
    result += ' ';                            // if you want a space in between
    result += arr[1][counter] || ' ';
    result += '\n'
    counter++
  }
  return result.slice(0, -1)
}

transpose(testArr) // yields:
                              "H W
                               e o
                               l r
                               l l
                               o d"
```

Comment: "If one string is longer than the other, there should be a space where the character would be"

Comment: Assuming same length input strings severely limits your input range in this scenario.